# Include 'blank' filters in dplyr filter chain in Shiny app

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have a `shiny` application with numerous user inputs including `numericInput` and `textInput` and `pickerInput`. These inputs are used to filter a dataframe.

In my filtering chain, however, I need to accept any combination of inputs, even if the user doesn't provide data for a given input. For example, a user may filter using just the `numericInput` field, or the `textInput` and `pickerInput` fields, while submitting no information in the `numericInput` field.

What would be the best way of achieving this, on the basis that the total number of user inputs could be *n* large? In essence, is it possible to keep all inputs in the filtering chain within `server`, but ignore those input fields where the user provides no input data?

Example app:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

data<-tibble(ref=c("ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "FGH", "FGH", "FGH"), 
             type=c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
             number=c("1", "17", "54", "23", "6", "87", "3"))



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      textInput("text", label = "Type in Ref", value = NULL),
      selectInput("select", label = "Select input", choices = c(unique(data$type))),
      numericInput("numeric", label = "Type in number", value = NULL)

      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput("data")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filterData = reactiveVal(data)

  filtered_df <- reactive({
    res <- filterData() %>% 
      filter(ref == input$text)

    res
    
  })
  

  output$data<-renderTable({
    filtered_df()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Expected outputs**

If someone filters on `ref=='XYZ'` only:

```
ref type number
XYZ A    54
XYZ A    23
```

If someone filters on `ref=='FGH'` *and* `type=='B'`:

```
ref type number
FGH B    3
```

I someone filters on `number==54` only:

```
ref type number
XYZ A    54
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to put several `if` conditions in `reactive()`:

```r
filtered_df <- reactive({
    
    res <- filterData()
    if (!is.null(input$text) && input$text != "") {
      res <- res %>% 
        filter(ref == input$text)
    }
    if (!is.null(input$select)) {
      res <- res %>% 
        filter(type == input$select)
    }
    if (!is.na(input$numeric)) {
      res <- res %>% 
        filter(number == input$numeric)
    }
    
    res
  })
```